# DataFrame group and shift to get previous column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF like so:

```
    asset_id    source_id   open_px close_px    start_bin           end_bin
0   1           a           None    10          2022-01-01 09:30:00 2022-01-01 10:00:00
1   1           a           None    10          2022-01-01 10:00:00 2022-01-01 10:30:00
2   2           a           None    101         2022-01-01 09:30:00 2022-01-01 10:00:00
3   2           a           None    500         2022-01-01 10:00:00 2022-01-01 10:30:00
4   2           a           None    600         2022-01-01 10:30:00 2022-01-01 11:00:00
```

code to generate:

```
rows=[
    [1, 'a', None, 10, datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 9, 30), datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 0)],
    [1, 'a', None, 10, datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 30)],
    [2, 'a', None, 101, datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 9, 30), datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 0)],
    [2, 'a', None, 500, datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 30)],
    [2, 'a', None, 600, datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 30), datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 11, 0)]
]

cols = ['asset_id', 'source_id', 'open_px', 'close_px', 'start_bin', 'end_bin']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=cols)
```

I want to get the `open_px` by getting the last close from the bin corresponding to this rows start_bin, but also grouped by asset_id, in the most pandas friendly way. (happy for the first entry in each to remain `None`). I do not want to brute force with a loop as the dataset is quite large.

Expected Output:

```
    asset_id    source_id   open_px close_px    start_bin           end_bin
0   1           a           None    10          2022-01-01 09:30:00 2022-01-01 10:00:00
1   1           a           10      10          2022-01-01 10:00:00 2022-01-01 10:30:00
2   2           a           None    101         2022-01-01 09:30:00 2022-01-01 10:00:00
3   2           a           101     500         2022-01-01 10:00:00 2022-01-01 10:30:00
4   2           a           500     600         2022-01-01 10:30:00 2022-01-01 11:00:00
```

Comment: Can you give an example of expected results?

Comment: added to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.sort_values(['asset_id','start_bin'], inplace=True)
df['open_px'] = df['close_px'].shift()
df.loc[~df['asset_id'].duplicated(),'open_px'] = None
print(df)

   asset_id source_id  open_px  close_px           start_bin             end_bin
0         1         a      NaN        10 2022-01-01 09:30:00 2022-01-01 10:00:00  
1         1         a     10.0        10 2022-01-01 10:00:00 2022-01-01 10:30:00  
2         2         a      NaN       101 2022-01-01 09:30:00 2022-01-01 10:00:00  
3         2         a    101.0       500 2022-01-01 10:00:00 2022-01-01 10:30:00  
4         2         a    500.0       600 2022-01-01 10:30:00 2022-01-01 11:00:00
```

Comment: This gives no consideration to the asset_id in the shift, it needs to be grouped per the original post, the true dataset is large and sorted by TS so asset_ids are mixed row to row.

Comment: A `sort_values` on `asset_id` up front would solve that.  Is that practical in your use case?

Comment: that may work, however, there may be some true duplicates in the values if the close stays the same for 2 bins in a row say. Have you an alternative line to clear the initial values than removing just dupes?

Comment: Sure.  Modify your example data to include the challenging scenarios you mention - like different dup types, etc.

Comment: Updated, one of the assets now has dupe values

Comment: I added the `sort_values` which I think is all that is needed to make this work for you.  Notice that when I check for dups I do it using `asset_id` column to find the first entry of the asset.  Then I set that `open_px` to `None`.  I think that maybe you thought I was checking for dups in the open or close columns.  Let me know if we need to further refine.